# Add language bar with two settings for all users in domain on local computer?

Tags: windows-7, domain, language, user-settings, windows

I have a Windows 7 computer that needs to have both English and Spanish (US) language settings enabled. It is on the domain. Multiple users will use this machine, and it will be the only machine with this setting.

The problem I'm having is that I can set the language settings as an admin, but they do not appear for other users, only for the admin user.

How do I set it so all users use these settings?

Comment: Have you tried configuring this settings locally through the control panel and then coping them to all new users? or the users profiles already exist? (you'll need to change their settings through registry)

Answer (score 1):

They will not appear for other users that already had signed in on this computer before. But they will appear for new users who sign into this computer. Just deleted all users before setting the languages.